# fo image align caption

Tags: image, alignment, xsl-fo, text-alignment

I would like to have image with caption printed below the image in **XSL-FO**. the caption should have right alignment.

I am using table for that. It prints images with captions but the problem is the alignemnt of the caption compared to the caption. If the alignment of the image is 'right' then all looks fine: caption is just below the image at the right side. but if the image is center or left then still at the far right of the page.

The problem is the table is full width of the page but the image is smaller. The problem can be solved if the width and the alignment of the table corresponds to the width and the alignment of the image.

will really appreciate help to resolve this issue.

regards,
rnv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to ensure the table is not taking the entire width of the page, but just the width it needs. This way, the table will be as wide as the image, and your caption will be aligned to the right, neatly under the image.

However, now you want your image to be in the center of the page. The solution could be to put the table in another table and let this outer table take the entire width of the page. A `fo:block` might also do the trick.